# Read CSV file and save in 2 d array

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to read a huge CSV file in 2 D array, there must be a better way to split the line and save it in the 2 D array in one step :s
Cheers

```
my $j = 0;
while (<IN>) 
{

    chomp ;
    my @cols=();
    @cols   = split(/,/); 
    shift(@cols) ; #to remove the first number which is a line header
    for(my $i=0; $i<11; $i++) 
    {
       $array[$i][$j]  = $cols[$i];
    }        
    $j++;    
}
```

Comment: What types are the values in the file?  If there are strings (possibly with quotes, etc), you'd probably be better off with the Text::CSV module.  If they are pure numbers, you may be OK with simple splitting as shown.

Comment: Are you intentionally making the rows the second index into the array or is that a typo/mistake?

Answer (score 12):

CSV is not trivial. Don't parse it yourself. Use a module like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV), which will do it correctly and fast.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my @data;   # 2D array for CSV data
my $file = 'something.csv';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) { 
    shift @$row;        # throw away first value
    push @data, $row;
}
```

That will get all your rows nicely in `@data`, without worrying about parsing CSV yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever find yourself reaching for the C-style for loop, then there's a good chance that your program design can be improved.

```
while (<IN>) {
    chomp;

    my @cols = split(/,/); 
    shift(@cols); #to remove the first number which is a line header

    push @array, \@cols;
}
```

This assumes that you have a CSV file that can be processed with a simple `split` (i.e. the records contain no embedded commas).

Answer (score 2):

*Aside:* You can simplify your code with:

```
my @cols = split /,/;
```

---

> Your assignment to `$array[$col][$row]` uses an unusual subscript order; it complicates life.
>   With your column/row assignment order in the array, I don't think there's a simpler way to do it.

---

*Alternative:*
If you were to reverse the order of the subscripts in the array (`$array[$row][$col]`), you could think about using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;
for (my $j = 0; <>; $j++) # For testing I used <> instead of <IN>
{
    chomp;
    $array[$j] = [ split /,/ ];
    shift @{$array[$j]};   # Remove the line label
}

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@array); $i++)
{
    for (my $j = 0; $j < scalar(@{$array[$i]}); $j++)
    {
        print "array[$i,$j] = $array[$i][$j]\n";
    }
}
```

Sample Data

```
label1,1,2,3
label2,3,2,1
label3,2,3,1
```

Sample Output

```
array[0,0] = 1
array[0,1] = 2
array[0,2] = 3
array[1,0] = 3
array[1,1] = 2
array[1,2] = 1
array[2,0] = 2
array[2,1] = 3
array[2,2] = 1
```